# Difference between const char * and char const *

Tags: c++

I just found some code that doesn't compiles because somewhere a type is

```
const char *
```

and somewhere else

```
char const *
```

It is customary to differentiate between these two forms and the meaning is different ?

I suppose that I could suppose in one case a pointer to a const char and in the other case an unmodifiable pointer to a char, but I am not sure of anything .

Answer (score 1):

The two are completely identical and interchangeable. If the const is before the *, it refers to the pointed-to data type. If the const is after the *, it refers to the pointer itself.

Comment: May be, but my code doesn't compiles !!!

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis What is the errormessage?

Comment: /home/gk/Dropbox/workspace01/napl03/napl_allocator.cpp:66: undefined reference to `assert0(bool, char const*)' While the library defines void assert0(bool f,const char *s);         void assert0(bool f,const char *s){if(!f){printf("%s\nn",s);exit(1);}}

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis The problem is something to do with not being able to find assert0. It's nothing to do with the pointer.